# Cómo mostrar un Array en una tabla HTML?

Tags: php

Tengo una duda, encontré este codigo en un tutorial para obtener proxies a traves de una página, funciona pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer que NO se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que mejor se vea en una tabla en HTML? Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pudieran ayudarme les agradecería, solo encuentro respuestas en inglés y no se nada de PHP :( solo HTML.

**Este es el código:**

```
    <?php 

/* Pagina */
/* https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list-$i.html */

//iniciar cURL

$curl = curl_init();

//Ajustes

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list-1.html');

$proxies = array();
$start_count = 1;
$end_count = 10;


for ($i = $start_count; $i <= $end_count; $i++) {
    //crear_url
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list-$i.html");
    
    //ejecutar url
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    
    //encontrar proxies
    preg_match_all("!\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:\d{2,4}!",$result,$matches);

    print_r($matches); die();

    //guardar proxies en array
    $proxies = array_merge($proxies, $matches[0]);

}

//cerrar curl
curl_close($curl);
print_r($proxies);

 ?>
```

Comment: Para ponerla asi creo que es una libreria que se llama Tables, si no mal recuerdo es un array a json o algo asi, toda la explicación de como mostrar los datos vienen en la pagina de la libreria, y si viene en ingles, pero puedes traducirla con el navegador

Comment: @Macx hola hermano, gracias por la respuesta, será Datatables.net? Lo veo súper dificil y no entiendo nada ):

Comment: algo simple es recorrer el array $proxies y con echo imprimir los tags html necesarios para dibujar la tabla...

Comment: @AbrahamChan bro, me podrías dar ejemplo con mi código? se que suena pretencioso, pero me ayudará a que en el futuro pueda hacerlo solo, te podría ayudar haciendo algo cool en html, soy bueno en eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que imprimir la información dentro de las etiquetas para tablas.
[html table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

El siguiente código imprime una tabla tal cual como esta tu codigo
NOTA: la función die(); termina la ejecución del scrip por lo que no estas obteniendo todas las proxies: en caso de que y quieras listar todas, comenta esta función y cambia la función printTable($matches); al final del scrip, después de
curl_close($curl);
<?php

```
    function printTable($proxies){?>
      
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>IP</th>
                <th>Puerto</th>
            </tr>
      <?php foreach($proxies[0] as $key => $proxy){?>
            <tr>
            <?php 
                $proxy = explode(':',$proxy);
            ?>
                <td><?php echo $key ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $proxy[0] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $proxy[1] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
        
    <?php }
    

/* Pagina */
/* https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list-$i.html */

//iniciar cURL

$curl = curl_init();

//Ajustes

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list-1.html');

$proxies = array();
$start_count = 1;
$end_count = 10;


for ($i = $start_count; $i <= $end_count; $i++) {
    //crear_url
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list-$i.html");
    
    //ejecutar url
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    
    //encontrar proxies
    preg_match_all("!\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:\d{2,4}!",$result,$matches);

    //print_r($matches); 
    printTable($matches);
    die();

    //guardar proxies en array
    $proxies = array_merge($proxies, $matches[0]);

}

//cerrar curl
curl_close($curl);
//print_r($proxies);
```

Comment: Hermano... Eres un ángel! te lo agradezco mucho, ya he personalizado mi tabla, de verdad gracias! Quedó bien, acá por si la quieres ver: https://imgur.com/bHlM1rD